# How to map a new object to an object with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-webapi

I am taking my first steps with Entity Framework Core 5 but I am struggling figure out how to add an object in an One-To-Many relationship defined by convention and fluent API. I used this approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration

I have 3 objects "Area", "FuelType" and "Generator" with 2 One-To-Many relationships. Multiple Generators can only belong to one Area/ FuelType.

```
public partial class Generator
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public int GeneratorAiID { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public Area Area { get; set; }

    public FuelType FuelType { get; set; }

}
```

I have a .NET Core Web API receiving (POST) a collection of objects:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateGeneratorCollection(
    IEnumerable<GeneratorForCreation> generatorCollection)

    {
        var generatorEntities = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Entities.Generator>>(generatorCollection);
        foreach (var generator in generatorEntities)
        {
            _tradingDashboardRepository.AddGenerator(generator);
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok("Added");
    }
```

With the initial object looking like this:

```
public partial class GeneratorForCreation
{
    [Required]

    public int GeneratorAiID { get; set; }

    [Required]

    public int FuelTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public int AreaAiId { get; set; }
    [Required]

    
}
```

However, how do I map this to the expected entity for the database?

If I use this:

```
    public void AddGenerator(Generator generator)
    {
        if (generator == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(generator));
        }

        _context.Generator.Add(generator);

    }
```

I receive the error message:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Generator_Area_AreaAiId"
because AutoMapper can't correctly map the properties.

What is the standard approach for dealing with this?

My DataContext looks like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Generator>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Area)
        .WithMany(b => b.Generators)
        .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Generator>()
        .HasOne(p => p.FuelType)
        .WithMany(b => b.Generators)
        .IsRequired();
```

Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: I can see that my question has been down-voted. It would be great if that person would just tell me whats wrong so I could improve.

Comment: Do you not need to set the Area and FuelType properties before you save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_Generator_Area_AreaAiId"

It means you are trying to insert a record with a value in the foreign key column that doesn't exist in the foreign table.

Insert Area and FuelType before inserting Generator.

Try debug to check the value of AreaId and FuelTypeId.

Meanwhile, the `RequiredAttribute` should put on the top of the fields.

```
public partial class Generator
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GeneratorAiID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FuelType))]
    public int FuelTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Area))]
    public int AreaAiId { get; set; }

    public Area Area { get; set; }

    public FuelType FuelType { get; set; }

}


public partial class GeneratorForCreation
{
    [Required]
    public int GeneratorAiID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FuelTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AreaAiId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for clearing this up. I think I got confused because I assumed the reference to the "Area"/"FuelType" object would automatically expose the ForeignKey of that object. In previous attempts I also did not use the Data Annotation. Thank you. It has become clear now.